# gitlab Connection refused - connect(2) (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)

Tags: git-clone, gitlab

My gitlab server is under router which redirects 80 and 22 ports. server has inner ip address and router has public address. When I do git clone gitlab@domainname:user/example.git I get

```
Warning: Permanently added 'domainname' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `initialize': Connection refused - connect(2) (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `open'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `block in connect'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:54:in `timeout'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:99:in `timeout'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `connect'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:755:in `do_start'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:744:in `start'
    from /home/git/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_net.rb:56:in `get'
    from /home/git/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_net.rb:17:in `allowed?'
    from /home/git/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_shell.rb:51:in `validate_access'
    from /home/git/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_shell.rb:21:in `exec'
    from /home/git/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-shell:16:in `<main>'
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

However, when I added `127.0.0.1 domainname` into /etc/hosts everything works fine. Is this normal? What security issues this can create?

Answer (score 0):

One of the other ports that needed to be forwarded is 443. Can you try that?

TJR

Comment: 433 is forwarded, however the problem still remain.

Comment: Please, don't feel insulted : under default settings, gitlab relies on ssh-key based authentication. Can you make sure that you have added the ssh-key of the client you are connecting from?

Comment: client ssh key is added through interface and I can see it in authorized_keys file on the server.